# Where condition based on month and year

Tags: sql-server, datetime

i have the following code:

```
select COUNT(STL.ITEID)

from STORETRADELINES STL

left join FINTRADE FT ON STL.FTRID=FT.ID

where RIGHT(CONVERT(datetime, FT.FTRDATE, 3), 5) < RIGHT(CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 3), 5) 
and FT.FTRDATE > CONVERT(datetime,'01.01.2017',103)
```

I want to select all the documents that fall between 01.01.2017 and 30.04.2017 (always, the last day of the previous month).

Seem's that this way is not good, because is returning all the docs from 01.01 until today.

Where am i wrong ? Btw, i use sql server 2008.

Thank you

Comment: `31.04.2017`? What calendar system are you using?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , dates are stored like this in FT.FTRDATE:
    
    2017-05-04 00:00:00.000

Comment: Humour doesn't always translate well on the internet. There's no 31st April this year.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Typo error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're doing string comparisons. Use date comparisons instead:

```
select COUNT(STL.ITEID)

from STORETRADELINES STL

left join FINTRADE FT ON STL.FTRID=FT.ID

where FT.FTRDATE < DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()),0)
and FT.FTRDATE >= '20170101'
```

Here, the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair of calls are rounding the current date down to the start of the current month.

You can use a similar `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair for your start-of-period condition, using `year` instead of `month` if you want this query to be generic for any current year

---

The reason you're "stringly-typed" code doesn't work is that your `CONVERT` calls are converting `datetime` values to `datetime`. The *style* parameter is ignored here since `datetime`s don't have a format. You then get an uncontrolled implicit conversion of the `datetime`s into `varchar` so that `RIGHT` can work, and it's *that* conversion that you should have tried to control.

As it is, this:

```
select RIGHT(CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 3), 5)
```

Generates:

```
:50AM
```

Which you can hopefully see is nothing like what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`dateadd(mm,datediff(mm, 0 , current_timestamp),0)` will return the first day of current month. 
Your query could be

```
SELECT COUNT(STL.ITEID)
FROM STORETRADELINES STL
   left join FINTRADE FT ON STL.FTRID=FT.ID
where 
FT.FTRDATE >=  '2017-01-01' AND FT.FTRDATE < dateadd(mm,datediff(mm, 0 , current_timestamp),0)
```

Comment: This will also return rows which occurred at precisely midnight on `20170501`, due to `BETWEEN` inclusive nature.